# UTS_RELEASE shows wrong version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, ubuntu-20.04

Currently I'm using linux-5.4.0-60-generic, and if I cat `utsrelease.h` I get the following.

```
$ cat /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic/include/generated/utsrelease.h
#define UTS_RELEASE "5.4.78"
```

This is making it very difficult to install any kernel module, because it compiles with vermagic set to `5.4.78`, and `uname -r` returns `5.4.0-60-generic`. To fix `utsrelease.h` I  can download the sources and recompile the kernel with a fix in `Makefile` to correct the version, but compiling the kernel takes a lot of time, and it goes back to that wrong UTS_RELEASE when I upgrade the kernel.

Am I messing up some step, or is this working as intended?

Comment: If the Makefile says 5.4.78, then I doubt you are using 5.4.0 source.

Comment: @stark How can I check this and be sure? As I said, I just downloaded 5.4.0 source and it says 5.4.78 on Makefile... The problem is that `uname -r` and `UTS_RELEASE` do not agree with each other.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  They refer to different things.

Comment: hmm.  I donwloaded Ubuntu kernel-headers and utsrelease.h matches the deb name, not the Makefile.

Comment: It is a problem because I am unable to run a kernel module I just compiled

Comment: Where did you get the files under /usr/src/linux-headers?

Comment: If I download and build the whole kernel source, utsrelease.h is generated from the source version in Makefile.  If I download the Ubuntu linux-headers, utsrelease.h is already there and does NOT match the Makefile; it is the Ubuntu kernel version.

Comment: I had never compiled a linux source and I wasn't being able to run a driver I just compiled, for my network interface controller. I fiddled around and discovered that it was complaining about vermagic, and found out the mismatch I talked about. Downloading headers wasn't enough for it to compile correctly, so I downloaded the source through `sudo apt install linux-source-5.4.0`, exploded the archive, modified the makefile, compiled the source and it just worked. Edit: For the header files, I got it through `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: When I downloaded the headers, the Makefile was showing 5.4.78.

output of `linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic$ cat ./include/generated/utsrelease.h`:
`#define UTS_RELEASE "5.4.78"`